# Android - Proper Way to Share Public Files Between Apps

Tags: android, xamarin, uri, android-7.0-nougat, android-fileprovider

#### The Issue

In the Nougat+ world of Android, Google is enforcing the `content://` Uris over `file://` Uris. This makes sense for app-private files, but not for system-wide or public ones. I have a file manager app that naturally needs to share the files on a user's phone with various viewer apps. This situation does not fit the rationale of the `content://` protocol, which is to temporarily grant access of my app's files to another app. The file `/sdcard/Downloads/kittens.png` is not private to my file manager, so it seems improper for my app to label kittens.png (a public file) as private and thus share to a viewer app over `content://`. A file manager by design is merely an organizer and convenient linkage between a user's files and their preferred apps, after all.

As the `file://` protocol is firmly frowned upon these days, I have tried to utilize the `content://` protocol with mixed results. Some apps respond to the `content://` Uri and process the file while others don't. Every viewer app I've tested, however, responds correctly to the `file://` protocol and is then able to process the file. A good example of this is VLC and jetAudio, my two favorite media players. VLC will play audio passed through both `content://` and `file://`, while jetAudio only plays audio passed by `file://`.

#### To sum up the problem

I need to be able to share virtually all files on the user's phone with *whatever unknown viewer apps* are installed, just as a file manager should be able to do. Some viewer apps (likely older ones that don't target 24+) do not correctly display files shared over `content://` - a problem that would make my file manager unusable. Other file manager apps avoid this problem by targeting a lower SDK or unsetting the restriction on `file://`, but I'm not certain if that is a good, future-proof option. **What is the proper (aka secure & lasting) way to solve this?**

### My Current Ideas

**Sharing by Content**

This is how I've tried sharing with `content://`, which fails for some viewer apps, like jetAudio.

*C# (I'm using Xamarin)*:

```
Intent viewFile = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
fileIntent.SetDataAndType(FileProvider.GetUriForFile(Application.Context, Application.Context.PackageName + ".provider", new Java.IO.File(fileFullpath)), fileMIME);
fileIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission | ActivityFlags.GrantWriteUriPermission);
...
StartActivity(viewFile);
```

*In the manifest*:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

*xml/provider_paths*:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

**Sharing by File**

I want to keep my target SDK at 25. As such, I could use `StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder().build());` or something similar to share files by `file://`. This works with virtually all viewer apps, but is clearly a workaround, not a solution. I'd like to avoid this if possible since I'm not certain how much longer this approach will be permitted as future versions of Android release.

**Superuser Aid**

If there's a bash utility or native code that can better solve this problem, I am absolutely open it.

Comment: Do you want to get other app's file in your app?

Comment: @Billy No, that's not it. "I need to be able to share virtually all files on the user's phone with whatever unknown viewer apps are installed, just as a file manager should be able to do." My app needs to post to whatever link-layer does the handshake between a Uri and a viewer app.